# MS Access VBA - Open form and get value from computed textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

This is about a more complex project but I managed to narrow down the problem to the following case.

In an Access form (`fSearch`) there is a button (`bCheck`). The `bCheck_Click` event
code aims at opening an existing excel file and fill in there a specific value.
I can get this value from a computed textbox (`tSumAmount`) of another form (`fMain`).

So at first I open `fMain`, then I open the excel file, and then I try to copy `tSumAmount`'s value in the excel file, which never happens.

Using `Debug.Print` I can see that right before coping the value, `tSumAmount` still has not been computed.
If code is interrupted, then ***it is*** computed and if the code continues (F5) then the value is copied correctly.

It seems like `tSumAmount` is not computed until `bCheck_Click` ends. Which is confusing as the `fMain`'s `Form_Load` event is fired first and there is plenty of time for it to finish before `bCheck_Click` attempts to copy the value.

So the question about the computed textboxes is, *when are they actually computed*? I am missing this time point and I don't know even if what I need is possible.
Any explanation appreciated. Also if this is not possible, I need this to work somehow.

```
Sub bCheck_Click()
Dim oXl As Excel.Application
Dim oWb As Excel.Workbook
    Search_It
    Set oXl = New Excel.Application
    oXl.DisplayAlerts = False
    oXl.Visible = True
    Set oWb = oXl.Workbooks.Open("full_path_of_excel_file")
'-> At this point tSumAmount has not been computed yet. Tried Sleep, still no luck.
Debug.Print "(" & Forms("fMain").tSumAmount & ")" '-> output: ()
    With oWb.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1") = Forms("fMain").tSumAmount
    End With
End Sub
    

Sub Search_It()
    'do stuff
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fMain"
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but have you had a look to `Form.Recalc` ? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.Form.Recalc

Comment: Why do you need to open a form just to pull a single aggregate value? Maybe use DSum() and pull from table.

Comment: @June7 you are right. The way I ask the question it seems unnecessary. Though as stated at the beginning, this is a more complex concept, meaning that in this case this form makes several other stuff before aggregating to this textbox. I would rather not making all this again and again.

Comment: @FunThomas thanks for the tip. I will try this as soon as possible and come back with the result.

Comment: @FunThomas your suggestion worked flawlessly. So simple. I wasn't aware of this method. Thanks again. Would you like to add it as an answer? If not then I will do it later on just to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @FunThomas's tip the working code is the following:

```
Sub bCheck_Click()
Dim oXl As Excel.Application
Dim oWb As Excel.Workbook
    Search_It
    Set oXl = New Excel.Application
    oXl.DisplayAlerts = False
    oXl.Visible = True
    Set oWb = oXl.Workbooks.Open("full_path_of_excel_file")
    Forms("fMain").Recalc
    With oWb.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A1") = Forms("fMain").tSumAmount
    End With
End Sub
    

Sub Search_It()
    'do stuff
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fMain"
End Sub
```